# Using Android Studio on a Surface Pro(5th gen)

Tags: cpu, virtualization, android-studio, microsoft-surface-pro

I am someone who wants to build an app using Android Studio. An important function of Android Studio is to test the app that is being developed. I tried testing on a virtual device but it refuses to work. The "intel x86 emulator accelerator (haxm installer)" SDK won't install and only returns the error:

> This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)
>   or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. 
>   Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the
>   Intel HAXM documentation for more information.

My Hyper-V is indeed disabled. I tried to download the HAXM directly from Intel's site and it gave me the same error. The only other possible reason would be that my CPU does not support Intel Virtualization Technology. This seemed unlikely to me since I figured there would be no reason for my new Surface Pro not to include it. After researching the topic, I downloaded the Intel Processor Identification Utility to verify if my CPU has Intel Virtualization Technology. To my surprise, it appeared not to be supported.

I have spent three days trying to test an app any way I can and nothing seems to work. I am frustrated with how difficult this process has been for such a basic function. I own a Surface Pro (2017) with Intel Core i5-7300U 8GB ram. I just want to know if anyone with this computer or similar circumstances has successfully used Android Studio and how.

Comment: Questions about Android devices are out of scope here at Super User.  **Worth pointing out your CPU actually does support VT-x.**

Comment: Make sure you have Core Isolation disabled, and any security software you have installed, is not configured to use VT-x otherwise Android Studio will not work.

Comment: So how would I disable Core Isolation. And if my CPU does have VT-x, then how do I "enable" it?

Comment: It should already been enabled.  How you disable Core Isolation is well documented. Your CPU absolutely supports VT-x

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get the simulator working. The problem was the Core Isolation feature "Memory Integrity" was on. All I had to do was turn it off. I did this by opening "Windows Defender Security System." Then I select "Device Security > Core Isolation Details" then turn off the Memory Integrity switch. After the computer restarted, the virtual device worked.